# XMLHTTPRequest Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, google-maps-api-3

i'm trying to do a request to a php file. I catch the longitude and latitude from a function in Maps API, and use AJAX to save this points in a MySQL database.

**AJAX**

```
 function salvaPonto(latitude, longitude){
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              data: {latitude: latitude,longitude: longitude},
              url: "http://localhost/dados/salvaPonto.php",
              datatype: 'JSONp',
              success: function(data) {
                alert("ok");
              },
              error: function(data){
                alert("erro");
              }
          });
        }
```

**PHP File**

```
<?php

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    error_reporting(0);
    $latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
    $longitude = $_GET['longitude'];

   $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ('Erro de conexão com o banco de dados');
    mysql_select_db('app') or die ('Erro ao selecionar banco de dados');

    $myquery = "INSERT INTO pontos(latitude, longitude) VALUES ('".$latitude."', '".$longitude."');";

    $result = mysql_query($myquery) or die("Query error:".mysql_error());
    mysql_close($conn);

    echo 1;   


?>
```

**Error:**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost/dados/salvaPonto.php?latitude=-22&longitude=-43. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: possible duplicate of [“No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: possibly related question: [XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445027/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-o)

Comment: See [Cross-Domain requests in Javascript](https://jvaneyck.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/cross-domain-requests-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucas you're misusing the `header` function, so your Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not set properly.  `header()` accepts the header name and value as one string, not two.  Change:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

To:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

[See docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)