# Codeigniter: AJAX fails to access the controller: Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

So I was trying my hands first time on Codeigniter. I tried to build a login system. Have a look here: http://www.henryspike.tk/udemy/

When you try to log in, it is supposed to use AJAX to send data to a controller but the chrome displays an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.henryspike.tk/udemy/index.php/main/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://henryspike.tk' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I searched for the issue and found it has something to do with Cross-Domain stuff. I did not try the remedies since I think that I aint using AJAX from another domain. The controller and the view/jQuery are present on the same domain.

Is it something because I have installed Codeigniter in a sub folder on my domain i.e Udemy! I would like to state that I edited the base url correctly to http://www.henryspike.tk/udemy in my config.php

Comment: can you tell me where to add the header? in which file?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  of the problem so we can see and not guess.

Comment: Well, visit http://www.henryspike.tk/udemy   try to log in with any email/password. Make sure you have console open. Then as soon as you click log in, AJAX is supposed to pass data to a Controller. but it does not and return a CORS error

Comment: can u show me a .htaccess in root folder?

Comment: I have no .htaccess file. One important thing to note, when I add the header stuff into my controller, it works all fine....But I want to know the reason behind the behavior...since I am on the same domain, why does it require a header before controller?

Comment: It works but the point here is asking....Why does it work this way? I mean I am on the same domain then why is it displaying an Origin error? Is it because I installed Codeigniter in a sub directory?

Comment: Alright. Please post as an answer so I can select yours. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Set a header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445027/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-o)

Maybe have problems with different ports,. It doesn't matter that they are on the same machine/hostname.

Answer (score 1):

`www` vs no `www` is considered different subdomain and therefore different origin.

Use a relative url

Comment: I have added 'www' in every URL....my every URL is absolute so that shouldnt be an issue

Comment: But error shown indicates you are opening page on non `www` domain. Show your ajax code

Comment: take a look                                                           $(".logButton").click(function () {
        
        $.ajax({
            
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://www.henryspike.tk/udemy/index.php/main/login",
            data: {email: $("#email").val(), password: $("#password").val()},
            success: function (data) {
                
                alert(data);
                
            }
            
        });
        
        return false;
        
    });

Comment: ok...and that has `www` in it but when you open page you are not using `www`

Comment: I cant understand...Please elaborate a little?

Comment: The page you make request from does not have `www` in address bar